# How to show custom pages one over another

Tags: drupal-7, overlay

I need to show one page over another for non-admin users much like overlay feature in Drupal7 applicable for admin users. I tried out overlay module and overlay UI module but not of much help.

All the overlaying pages are custom created and will be invoked on working page after clicking a link.

Please refer me a solution which should work across all browsers and I can adjust width and height of overlaying page.I want to implement this solution for pop up messages, warning and alert also.Please see below image for reference:

[image]

Need your much appreciated help.

Answer (score 0):

I would check out [ctools modal forms](https://drupal.org/project/modal_forms) for forms, and you can use [colorbox_node](https://drupal.org/project/colorbox_node) for pretty much everything else.